# Unexpected response code: 404 error in javascript console while trying to connect Django channels

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to route websocket in following path.

```
matrix.routing -> ws_consumer.routing -> chat.routing.
```

## application structure

```
/matrix ->
    /matrix
    /wsconsumer
    /chat
```

`matrix` is my application name and other two (`ws_consumer`, `chat`) are apps.
Configurations in those files are as follows

## matrix.routing.py

```
ws_consumer_regex = r'^/ws_consumer'

channel_routing = [
    include('ws_consumer.routing', path=ws_consumer_regex),
]
```

## ws_consumer.routing.py

```
chat_regex = r'^/chat'
notification_regex = r'^/notification'

channel_routing = [
    include('chat.routing', path=chat_regex),
    include('notification.routing', path=notification_regex),
]
```

## chat.routing.py

```
group_chat_name_regex = r'^/(?P<group_name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$'

group_chat_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', consumers.group_chat_connect, path=group_chat_name_regex),
    route('websocket.receive', consumers.group_chat_receive, path=group_chat_name_regex),
    route('websocket.disconnect', consumers.group_chat_disconnect, path=group_chat_name_regex),
]


group_chat_global_regex = r'^/group'

channel_routing = [
    include(group_chat_routing, path=group_chat_global_regex),
]
```

## client.html

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws_consumer/chat/group/test/');
socket.onopen = function open() {...};

socket.onmessage = function (event) {...};

if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
socket.onopen();
}
```

Server is starting without any issue under these configuration. But in console I'm getting below error.

## javascript console

```
VM2306:35 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/ws_consumer/chat/group/test/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

## python console

```
Not Found: /ws_consumer/chat/group/test/
[19/Mar/2017 23:42:39] "GET /ws_consumer/chat/group/test/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2202
```

I also tried routing directly to the consumer in `matrix.routing.py` which takes me to the same error.

## matrix.routing.py

```
from chat.consumers import group_chat_connect #consumer method
channel_routing = [
    route('websocket.connect', group_chat_connect)
]
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was not including "channels" to INSTALLED_APPS of settings.py